# What is the significance of the "Sign Up" button on Facebook's new login page?

Tags: usability, website-design, facebook

So Facebook updated their login page. I couldn't help but wonder the reason behind having a Sign Up button in the header when there already is a Sign Up form in the body section.

What aspect of UX does it improve?

[image: FB]

Comment: I think Facebook is A\B testing its login page to see if it can drive greater conversions.

Comment: If you want the real answer you might try Quora to get somebody on the Facebook design team. Other answers would fall under speculation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you still seeing that? I see no such "Sign Up" button at the top, only a "Log In" button.

[image]

which makes me think it may have been a temporary glitch or oversight.

Comment: Facebook is known to roll out features/improvements in an iterative manner. E.g. They start with 1% of their user base. Nothing crashes? Up to 2%. Etc